# EV3 brick cannot connect my to computer

Tags: ev3

I can't connect my brick to my computer. It keeps saying it can't communicate with the brick. My brick has no firmware. My friend said to change the USB cable but it still doesn't work. I can't connect it via Bluetooth either.

Comment: Try disabling antivirus software.

Answer (score 3):

Try to update your firmware via EV3 software: http://www.thenxtstep.com/2013/08/how-to-update-your-ev3-firmware.html

Comment: This doesn't work for me after I foolishly interrupted a firmware update.  By following the reset steps I can get the brick to say it is updating, but the EV3 software says there is no brick attached.