EV3 Brick not connecting to computer
I have a classroom set of 12 EV3 bricks. We are using microsoft makecode to program these bricks and putting the files on the bricks by dragging them over to the ev3 file drive. This worked fine for several weeks, but one by one the bricks have stopped showing up as files. They also aren't detected by the EV3 classroom app, or the older LEGO Mindstorms education app (which I used to update the bricks to the latest version in the first place). I have tried resetting the bricks, swapping cables / computers and power cycling the bricks with no success. Any other troubleshooting steps I could take?

Did you try reinstalling the firmware? Version 1.10E is the only version that works with MakeCode. Version 1.09E works best with the official LEGO apps.

All of the bricks have 1.10E. I'm not able to connect to the computer to reinstall the firmware (the online flasher and the older Lego app both dont recognize the bricks)

Is there any chance a policy was rolled out to the Windows computers that disallows the use of USB drives?

If you hold down the right button while powering on the EV3, it will force the EV3 into firmware update mode, they you should be able to flash the firmware (https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/8630/3498).
